# merge and expand 2 dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I need a way to merge and expand two dataframes. So in this simplified example I need to merge by `type` and expand `plot` so that it appears in each row of the new dataframe where it is matched by `type`. The example output below has only been provided for the first 2 rows of df1 but the final dataFrame in this example should have 50 rows. Is there an easy way to do this?

data:

```
type <- c("control","treat","treat","control","control")
plot <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
df1 <- data.frame(plot, type)
bands <- c(seq(1,10),seq(1,10))
otherInfo <- rep("stuff", 20)
otherInfo2 <- rep("things",20)
type <- c(rep("control",10),rep("treat",10))
df2 <- data.frame(bands, otherInfo, otherInfo2, type)
```

dataFrame1:

```
plot    type
  1 control
  2   treat
  3   treat
  4 control
  5 control
```

dataFrame2:

```
bands otherInfo otherInfo2    type
1      stuff        things  control
2      stuff        things  control
3      stuff        things  control
4      stuff        things  control
5      stuff        things  control
6      stuff        things  control
7      stuff        things  control
8      stuff        things  control
9      stuff        things  control
10     stuff        things  control
1      stuff        things    treat
2      stuff        things    treat
3      stuff        things    treat
4      stuff        things    treat
5      stuff        things    treat
6      stuff        things    treat
7      stuff        things    treat
8      stuff        things    treat
9      stuff        things    treat
10     stuff        things    treat
```

dataFrame3 (desired output)

```
bands otherInfo otherInfo2  type  plot
   1        stuff things control   1
   2        stuff things control   1
   3        stuff things control   1
   4        stuff things control   1
   5        stuff things control   1
   6        stuff things control   1
   7        stuff things control   1 
   8        stuff things control   1 
   9        stuff things control   1
  10        stuff things control   1
   1        stuff things treat     2
   2        stuff things treat     2
   3        stuff things treat     2
   4        stuff things treat     2 
   5        stuff things treat     2
   6        stuff things treat     2
   7        stuff things treat     2
   8        stuff things treat     2
   9        stuff things treat     2
  10        stuff things treat     2
etc...
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can tell from the limited output you provided what exactly the desired output is. Values with `etc...` aren't very useful if the pattern isn't made clear. Should all values that have "treat" be returned with both plot=2 and plot=3? Isn't that was a basic merge does? `merge(dataFrame1, dataFrame2)`.

Comment: the reproducible code you provided doesn't match the outputs you've posted

Comment: ooops, it does now

Comment: What is wrong with a simple `merge` on *type*?

Comment: maybe this is hard to see in the example, but for each row of dataframe 1 it should be expanded by the 10 rows in dataframe 2 that match that type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df3 = do.call(rbind,  lapply(split(df2, df2$bands), function(x)
    merge(x, df1, by = "type", all = TRUE)))
NROW(df3)
# [1] 50
```

You may have to further reorder the rows if that is important.